Сборка JS: ExtJs + lib + Uglify + Webpack
В компании есть система сборки js-скриптов такого плана: есть файл php, который определяет, какие файлы js собирать в один файл, а какие - в другой. После чего, php-скрипт читает содержимое всех файлов, втыкает их по порядку друг за другом в src_main.js, а после прогоняет этот файл через UglifyJS.
Появилась необходимость добавить одну npm-либу для всего этого добра, но возник вопрос: uglify не хочет собирать один файл, натыканный из файлов этой либы, т.к. в ней штук 10 export default и раза в 3 больше импортов. Хотел собрать через вебпак, но он ни в какую не хочет выходить за пределы файла с точкой входа (т.е. в app.js подключаются extjs-модули, а он их даже не ищет и не подключает). Думал собрать только либу через webpack - там происходит обфусцированние кода, имена классов теряются.
Есть какие-то идеи?

Идеи есть, первая из них это увидеть ваш вебпак конфиг для анализа.
